# how to find AVG of time in snowflake

Tags: sql, time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, average

I have a timestamp column with following sample data:

```
JOB_ID  OOB_TIMESTAMP
1495576 NULL
1495576 2022-08-25 18:29:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-24 19:56:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-23 17:32:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-22 17:12:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-21 15:35:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-20 15:41:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-19 17:09:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-18 17:25:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-17 17:38:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-16 20:00:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-15 14:02:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-14 12:01:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-13 13:09:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-12 15:19:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-11 14:14:00.000 -0700
1495576 2022-08-10 16:24:00.000 -0700
```

I need to ignore the date field and calculate the average of ONLY time per job_id

expected answer:
something like --> `15:30:00.000 -0700`

this allows me to extract just the time from timestamp `to_time(to_timestamp_tz(value:dailyOutOfBudgetDatetime::string))`
but `avg(to_time(to_timestamp_tz(value:dailyOutOfBudgetDatetime::string)))` doesn't work throwing an error

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @lemon I tried `avg(date_part(epoch_second , to_timestamp_tz(OOB_TIMESTAMP::string))))` but thats giving me `2022-08-17 21:34:45.517 -0700`
but looking at the data, I think the avg should be somewhere between `15:00-17:00`

Comment: Your problem is linked to the fact that you carry the date with you. You could try extracting the time from the timestamps first, then carry out same task as you're already doing.

Comment: deg , whatever you tried that includes day aswell, so you got the avg in days

Comment: yeah I am not able to perform avg only on the extracted time;

I tried ```avg(to_time(to_timestamp_tz(value:dailyOutOfBudgetDatetime::string)))``` but it doesn't allow me to average time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select JOB_ID , avg_seconds ,
     floor(avg_seconds/3600) as hour,
    floor((avg_seconds%3600)/60) as min, 
    floor(avg_seconds%60) as sec
    from (select JOB_ID ,
    avg(date_part(epoch_second , to_timestamp(OOB_TIMESTAMP::string))- date_part(epoch_second , to_timestamp(SUBSTR(OOB_TIMESTAMP , 1,10 )::string))) as
    avg_seconds
    from  ( select 1495576 as JOB_ID ,  NULL as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-25 18:29:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-24 19:56:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-23 17:32:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-22 17:12:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-21 15:35:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-20 15:41:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-19 17:09:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-18 17:25:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-17 17:38:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-16 20:00:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-15 14:02:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-14 12:01:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-13 13:09:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-12 15:19:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-11 14:14:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP UNION
    select 1495576 as JOB_ID , '2022-08-10 16:24:00.000 -0700' as OOB_TIMESTAMP  ) 
    group by JOB_ID )
```

I have intentionally ignored Time Zone as we need to find avg of time only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate average at hour and minute level seperately and then combine and cast to time.

Check if below query helps

```
select (avg(date_part('HH',to_timestamp_tz(OOB_TIMESTAMP::string)))::int::varchar
||':'|| avg(date_part('MI',to_timestamp_tz(OOB_TIMESTAMP::string)))::int::varchar||':00')::time avgTime
from my_table;
```